# When does $A$ iff $B$, imply $A=B$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, type-theory

I understand that it goes in the other direction, that is, if $A=B$, then $A$ if and only if $B$ is also true.

(*Just do a proof by contradiction, given $A=B$ assume $\lnot(A\leftrightarrow B)$, then $\lnot(A\leftrightarrow A)$, so the assumption was wrong and $A=B$ implies $A\leftrightarrow B$.*)

However I want to know under what conditions does the implication go the other way? Is there any general set of requirements I can look for, to know that it will hold in the reverse case? Under what special circumstances can I conclude $A=B$ when I already know $A\leftrightarrow B$?

You are free to interpret $A$ and $B$ as whatever object you wish. If it helps, they can be restricted to a certain type to answer the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $A=B$?  What sort of objects are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I've seen the implication you're asking about be referred to by the name *propositional extensionality*.  (And then, for example, propositional extensionality does hold in the internal logic of a topos - assuming that $A$ and $B$ are of type $\Omega$.)

Comment: On the other hand, propositional extensionality often doesn't hold in Martin-Lof based type theories (unless you add it as an axiom after the fact).

Comment: @EricWofsey I have clarified this now.

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote? I can't improve the question without knowing what is wrong with it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am honestly at a loss as to what to add. It was meant to be open ended so that any answerer could choose their own requirements on $A$ and $B$ to answer the question. If I knew what $A$ and $B$ needed to be restricted to in the first place, I wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: I'll try again... In FOL, if $A$ and $B$ are formulas ("statements"), then $(A \leftrightarrow B)$ is a syntactically correct formula while $A=B$ is **meaningless**. IF $A$ and $B$ are *terms* ("names" for objects), then $A=B$ is a syntactically correct formula while $(A \leftrightarrow B)$ is meaningless. Up to you...

Comment: Maybe you are working in a different "environment"... Following Daniel's suggestion, see [propositional extensionality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositional+extensionality). If so, please add the tag "type-theory" and I'll remove my comemnts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for your comments. I wasn't able to restrict the types without answering the question, but upon trying to resolve this issue, I ended up answering my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to the question by looking into the propositional extensionality that @Daniel Schepler linked in a comment. The trick is to take $A$ and $B$ as propositions in the case of $A\leftrightarrow B$, and as names for propositions (denoted as $'A'$ and $'B'$) in the case of $'A'='B'$. Then the implication, if $A\leftrightarrow B$ then $'A'='B'$ holds.

Reference:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositional+extensionality

Answer (score 2):

There are no logic statements $A$ such that for all statements $B$, knowing that $A \leftrightarrow B$ ensures that $B$ is the exact same statement as $A$ (that is, the exact same string of symbols), since any statement $A$ is equivalent to $(True) \rightarrow A$, which is a longer string of symbols.

Of course, you could try putting conditions on both $A$ and $B$, but I'm not sure what you'd accomplish at that point since you get awfully close to having the condition be that $A$ and $B$ are in fact equal.